# Differences between type="image" and type="submit"?

Tags: html, http, forms

(This question is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081568/asp-net-post-through-c-application))

I've a simple form:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="http://www.startupseeds.com/Default.aspx">
        <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="..." />
        <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWCALMyNWrBQKoz5H1CALlmOb9DgKmz6HzAwKf8bOXCQKC7qLKAwK5kNvVAQKk7amsA53tGBGr+Ji7LTI0eYkvquMZrF/g" />
        <input name="ctl00$Login1$tbEmail" type="text" />
        <input name="ctl00$Login1$tbPassword" type="password" />

        <input type="image" name="ctl00$Login1$ibLogin" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I Change this:

```
<input type="image" name="ctl00$Login1$ibLogin" />
```

to this:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$Login1$ibLogin" />
```

...it doesn't work. The only difference in this code is `type="submit"` instead of `type="image"`. I didn't know even that there are differences between them (in the key/value in http) - How can I get "submit" to work?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using any javascript with this form? For validation, perhaps?

Comment: What does it do when it doesn't work?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you not want image? They both submit forms, so if you want an image, I think the 'type=image' would be best. If you don't want an image, then you shouldn't be using an ImageButton in ASP.NET. (I assume ctl00$Login1$ibLogin is an ImageButton type?)

Comment: I'm not using javascript in this form. And type="image" submitting to default.aspx connected, and type="submit" just submitting to the login form...

Comment: where are you changing the input type, on the client or on the server?

Comment: How can this be the full code? It looks like the generated html from an aspx page, not the aspx page itself. Could you please describe the error or anomaly that you get, including the original aspx code?

Comment: Yes, it is generated html from an aspx page, but I removed alot of things, and when I change `image` to `button` it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that:

```
<input type="image" name="ctl00$Login1$ibLogin" />
```

will result in two form fields: `ctl00$Login1$ibLogin.x` and `ctl00$Login1$ibLogin.y` to indicate what part of the image was clicked, although you have no image in your markup.

From [17.4.1 Control types created with INPUT](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.4.1) of the [HTML 4.01 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/):

> **image**
>
> Creates a graphical [submit
>   button](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#submit-button). The value of the
>   [`src`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-src) attribute specifies the URI
>   of the image that will decorate the
>   button. For accessibility reasons,
>   authors should provide [alternate
>   text](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/objects.html#alternate-text) for the image via the
>   [alt](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/objects.html#adef-alt) attribute.
>
> When a pointing device is used to
>   click on the image, the form is
>   submitted and the click coordinates
>   passed to the server. The x value is
>   measured in [pixels](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-pixels) from the left
>   of the image, and the y value in
>   pixels from the top of the image. The
>   submitted data includes name.x=x-value
>   and name.y=y-value where "name" is the
>   value of the `name` attribute, and
>   x-value and y-value are the x and y
>   coordinate values, respectively.

Comment: ...and this fails in ASP.NET because it doesn't expect those parameter names back. To cover this, just use `input type="submit"` with a CSS background image. You also apparently don't need an image map, but *just* a button with a background image.

Comment: @BalusC: can't ASP.NET handle image maps? Or is there some explicit mechanism that ends up using `usemap`?

Comment: I should have been less generic. I actually meant the code behind the form action.

Comment: I added two hidden inputs `ctl00$Login1$ibLogin.x` and `ctl00$Login1$ibLogin.y` and it is works now! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you'd like an asp.net page like this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" action="http://www.startupseeds.com/Default.aspx">
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbTextBox" runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbPassWord" runat="server" TextMode="Password" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
</div>
</form>
```

However, it depends on your target site if this kind of http-post actions are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your backend code is checking for the existence of an `ibLogin.x` or `ibLogin.y` POST parameters which are sent when you click an `<input type="image">` and represent the coordinates of the click. An `<input type="submit">`, on the other hand, will post an `ibLogin` parameter.

Answer (score -1):

need the src attribute that point a image url...

```
<input type="image" src="image_url" name="ctl00$Login1$ibLogin" />
```

EDIT:http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_input_type.asp

> defines an image as a submit button.
>
> The src and alt attribute are required
>   with .

Answer (score -3):

A submit button created using  is rather a drab looking gray colored entity, unless you know style sheets. while By placing input type=image in place of input type=submit you can place an image in place of the default submit button. as example shown

< input type="image" src="images/submit.jpg" value="Submit" alt="Submit" >